# Google In App Purchase Integration Working Example on 2020 May

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase

This is not a question actually. I spent some time on this, so I am putting here the steps involved to make an in-app purchase.

added dependencies

```
//billing-client
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:2.2.1'
```

added permission in manifest

1. Created application in Play Console.
2. Play Console -> settings -> Pricing Template :: added pricing template.
3. Select Application Form Console -> Store Presence -> In-App Products -> Managed
   Products -> Create a Managed Product.
4. For Testing, first of all, you need to release a build as Alpha (with some testing mail id registered in closed track.)
5. After Successful publication you can use the same build (maybe needed the same version code and version number) (**Both debug and Release works**) for test the purchase.

   6. Ensure the testing mail IDs are google ids (@gmail.com)

Here are the code snippets that I have used for billing.

```
implement PurchasesUpdatedListener, on fragment or activity
```

Setup BIlling Client

```
    private fun setupBillingClient() {
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(mainActivity)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .setListener(this)
        .build()
    billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
        override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                // The BillingClient is setup
                log("Setup Billing Done")
                loadAllSKUs()
            }
        }

        override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            log("Failed")

        }
    })
}
```

Load All Skus (Ids of your purchasing templates (use arraylist))

```
    private fun loadAllSKUs() = if (billingClient.isReady) {
    val params = SkuDetailsParams
        .newBuilder()
        .setSkusList(skuList)
        .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
        .build()
    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params) { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->
        // Process the result.
        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList.isNotEmpty()) {
            for (skuDetails in skuDetailsList) {
                if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList.isNotEmpty()) {
                    this.skuDetailsList = skuDetailsList
                }
            }
        }
    }

} else {
    log("Billing Client not ready")
}
```

Make Google Payment

```
    private fun invokeGooglePayPayment(skuDetails: SkuDetails) {
    val billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams
        .newBuilder()
        .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
        .build()
    billingClient.launchBillingFlow(mainActivity, billingFlowParams)
}
```

**If you need to purchase again on the same in-app purchase item you can use this code,**

```
    override fun onPurchasesUpdated(
    billingResult: BillingResult?,
    purchases: MutableList<Purchase>?
) {
    //todo remove this function only for token log
    if (!purchases.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        for (purchase in purchases) {
            Log.e("Purchase Token" + purchase.purchaseToken, "OK")
        }
    }
    if (billingResult?.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
        for (purchase in purchases) {
            acknowledgePurchase(purchase) // do after purchase
        }
    } else if (billingResult?.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
        //todo
    } else if (billingResult?.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
        val consumeParams = ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
            .setPurchaseToken("inapp:${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}:${selectedSkuDetails?.sku}")
            .build()
        runBlocking {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                billingClient.consumePurchase(consumeParams)
            }
            MainScope().launch {
                invokeGooglePayPayment(selectedSkuDetails!!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe putting on the medium will bring you more claps to the contribution and provide the github links to them.

Comment: I think most of the devs search for a solution in StackOverflow first. :D :D

Comment: I thought you were asking for a working example :)